# How to add Users menu item in our module?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i try it in this way.but unable to create users.please advice me to do that

```
    <record id="action_res_users" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Users</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.users</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="action_res_users" id="menu_action_res_users"
        parent="menu_bpl_registers" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code seems fine. Did you update your module after running OpenERP server ? If you already did it and still menu is not coming, I can suggest You to try it by creating a new database.